# Find child table with foreign key in t4 template

Tags: visual-studio-2013, foreign-keys, t4

I am pretty new to using T4 templates to generate POCOs and I have a working series of templates now that generate my DTO, DAL and Manager objects as well as the associated CRUD SQL files, history trigger and table.

It works great for individual tables, but I have been unable to figure out how to include the child tables in the DTO and DAL. Essentially, I want to create Read Only properties in my DTO and the Get Data methods for them in the DAL object for the related child DTO of the foreign key.

Here is my DTOGenerator.tt which is executed from another .tt taking in the Table, Namespace, Ddestination folder and a string to represent the user executing the template.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<#@ import namespace="System" #><##>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #><##>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #><##>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo"#><##>
<#@assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo"#><##>
<#@assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc"#><##>
<#@import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo"#><##>
<#+public void GenerateDTO(Table target_table, string classNamespace, string destinationFolder, string executed_by)
{
    // StringBuilders for Fields, Properties and Parameters.
    StringBuilder stbMembers = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder stbUserSaveEditMembers = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder stbAccessors = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder stbUserSaveEditAccessors = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder stbConstructorParameters = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder stbClassProperties = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder stbUserSaveEditClassProperties = new StringBuilder();

    // Keep count so we don't whitespace the last property/column
    int columnCount = target_table.Columns.Count;
    int i = 0;
    string col_identity = string.Empty;

    // Iterate all columns
    foreach (Column col in target_table.Columns)
    {
        i++;
        string propertyType = GetNetDataType(col.DataType.Name);

        // If we can't map it, skip it
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyType))
        {
            // Skip
            continue;
        }

        // Make propertytype nullable for nullable columns
        if (col.Nullable && propertyType != "string" && propertyType != "byte[]")
        {
            propertyType += "?";
        }

        // Build Fields & Class Properties
        string col_name = SnakeCaseToCamelCase(col.Name);

        // Capture Identity column name
        if(col.Identity)
        {
            col_identity = col_name;
        }
        else if (col.IsForeignKey)
        {
            //Create Read Only property to return child DTO via the child table DAL
        }

        // TABLE
        // Members
        stbMembers.Append("private ").Append(propertyType).Append(" _").Append(col.Name).Append(";\r\n\t\t");

        // Accessors
        if(i>1){stbAccessors.Append("\t\t");}
        stbAccessors.Append("[DataMember()]\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\tpublic ").Append(propertyType).Append(" ").Append(col_name).Append("\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t{\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\tget { return").Append(" _").Append(col.Name).Append("; }\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\tset\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t{\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t\tif (").Append("_").Append(col.Name).Append(" == value){ return; }\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t\t_").Append(col.Name).Append(" = value;\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t\tChanged = true;\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t}\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t}\r\n\r\n");

        // Class Properties
        stbClassProperties.Append("_").Append(col.Name).Append(" =").Append(" p").Append(col_name).Append(";");
        if(i < columnCount)
        {
            stbClassProperties.Append("\r\n\t\t\t");
        }

        // Class Parameters
        stbConstructorParameters.Append(propertyType).Append(" p").Append(col_name);
        if(i < columnCount)
        {
            stbConstructorParameters.Append(",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
        }
    }
#>
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization; 
namespace <#=classNamespace #>
{
    #region " History "

    // <remarks>
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Purpose       : Data Transfer Object for <#=target_table.Name #>
    // T4 Template   : DTOGenerator.tt
    // Date Created  : <#=DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy")#>
    // Created By    : <#=executed_by#>
    // Notice        : Copyright © <#=DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy")#> GooeyPC, All rights reserved.
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // History:
    // 
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // </remarks>

    #endregion

    [DataContract()]
    public class <#=target_table.Name #>DTO
    {
       #region " _MEMBERS "

        // TABLE FIELDS 
        <#=stbMembers.ToString() #>
        #endregion

        #region " ACCESSORS "

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns TRUE if data on this object record has changed
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember()]
        public bool Changed { get; set; }

        <#=stbAccessors.ToString() #>
        #endregion

        #region " PROPERTIES - READ ONLY "

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns TRUE if primary key id != 0 (i.e. valid primary key id exists.)
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool RecordExists
        {
            get { return (<#=col_identity #> != 0); }
        }

        #endregion

        #region " CONSTRUCTORS "

        /// <summary>
        /// Description of <#=target_table.Name #>
        /// </summary>
        public <#=target_table.Name #>DTO()
        {
            // Default constructor is needed
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Description of <#=target_table.Name #>
        /// </summary>
        public <#=target_table.Name #>DTO(<#=stbConstructorParameters.ToString() #>)
        {            
            // Set Class Properties
            <#=stbClassProperties.ToString() #>
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
<#+
    // Write new class to its own file
    SaveOutput(destinationFolder, target_table.Name + "DTO.cs");}
#>
```

Comment: Still trying to solve this if anyone can help.

Comment: OKay, so I did some more research, and I'm beginning to get the impression that I shouldn't do this as it exposes the DTO to the DataLayer; which is apparently not good.  

Would still like some thoughts on this.  Thanks.